# I need validate some fields in xsl by calling non-static method of java class

Tags: java, xslt

I need validate some fields in xsl by calling *non-static* method of java class **Validator**.
I want to create object of this class and pass it to xsl. After that - i want to check if errors found.

If i make methods of class **Valifator** static - all works fine.
OR:
If i create object of class **Validator** in xsl - all works fine too.

But how work with non-static methods?

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
xmlns:validatorns="xalan://project.xmlxsl.xml.Validator"
extension-element-prefixes="validatorns">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="name" />
<xsl:param name="validator" />

<xsl:variable name="checkName" select="validatorns:checkName($validator,$name)" />
...
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$checkName">
...
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have troubles understanding your question. Please rephrase. Maybe share some of the Java code with us, too.

Comment: Sorry. I am rephrase my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a value returned from the XSLT other than the transformed documents sounds a little weird for my taste. But I guess you could use `ThreadLocal`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some kind of unqiue object identifier in the XSL, you can use a static registry for your Validator class.

So you create a Validator, register it for the document, and when `checkName` is invoked with the proper ID, the registry will find the matching Validator and use it.

After transforming the document, you can then unregister the Validator. Make sure to use a synchronized access to the registry hashmap to get thread safety.